# Junit test of a class requires objects of other classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I have a class defined as such:

```
public class Monster {
    public static final int ARENA_SIZE = 480;

    public int health; //can be negative since it will then be removed
    public int speed;
    public int counter;
    public int x; //current position
    public int y; //current position
    public mapObject next;
    public void nextAlgorithm(mapObject[][] map) {
        aNode[][] aNodeMap = newANodeMap(map); //1. create a new aNodeMap

        PriorityQueue<aNode> pq = newPriorityMap(aNodeMap[this.x][this.y]); //2. create a new priority queue with starting point added
        aNode current;

        while (pq.isEmpty() == false) {
            current = pq.poll();
            if (endPointReached(current.x, current.y)) //3. Is the end point reached?
                break;
            aNode[] neighbours = findNeighbour(current.x, current.y, aNodeMap); //4. The end point isn't reached, find me the neigbours
            for (aNode neighbour : neighbours) //5. process all my neighbours
                processNeighbour(current, neighbour, pq);
        }
        next = updateNext(aNodeMap[ARENA_SIZE - 1][ARENA_SIZE - 1], this.x, this.y); //6. Update my next after all these work
    }
```

Simply put, there is an algorithm that requires input from other class, the mapObject, which is also another self-written package by me.

My question is, apart from

```
import MapObject.*;
```

in junit that allows me to initialize a fixture in

```
@Before
```

Are there any better ways?

Comment: How does it require an object of the `mapObject` class? It looks like it creates one (with `newANodeMap`.

Comment: In the function signature of nextAlgorithm, a mapObject[][] is required for replication. Therefore, it requires an object of the mapObject class. Second, it creates one newANodeMap is a fact, under the assumption that it needs an mapObject[][] object to replicate. Therefore, I need mapObject in the test case. May I ask which part of the question should I modify to make it clearer to others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably better to create the input object (i.e. the `mapObject[][]`) in the test case itself, rather than in a `@Before` method. This allows you to create several test cases with different input objects.

Ie

```
@Test void testWithSpecificArrayConfiguration1() {
    mapObject[][] objectConfig1 = createConfig1();
    testMonster.nextAlgorith(objectConfig1);
    // verification steps for config 1
}
@Test void testWithSpecificArrayConfiguration2() {
    mapObject[][] objectConfig2 = createConfig2();
    testMonster.nextAlgorith(objectConfig2);
    // verification steps for config 2
}
```

As a note, it doesn't feel right that the input is a `mapObject`, but the actual algorithm works on an `aNode[][]`; but it's hard to tell without knowing the context of the code.

Comment: Thanks, I will put an update on the post about the newANode issue. Since I am new to JUnit, is it normal to import self-written package for another classes when testing for this class? If not, are there any methods offered by JUnit to perform this function, i.e., import classes not the same as the current class in current test unit.

Comment: @AndesLam A unit test will always need to include all classes that are included in the class being tested. If an import feels wrong to you, you may abstract from the included class by introducing an interface for it, so you will only need to import the interface. This usually makes for better code because you're writing against an abstraction rather than an implementation.